# Python - Swap consecutive elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to swap the consecutive elements of a list such that the first element will go to the last. eg `[4, 7, 3, 4, 3]` should print as `[7,3,4,3,4]`
This is the code I've written but it doesn't work right. How can I modify it to get it working?

```
ls = [4, 7, 3, 4, 3]
i=0
b=1
while i+1<len(ls):
    ls[i]=a
    ls[i]=ls[i+1]
    ls[i+1]=a
    i+=1
print ls
```

I do not want to just switch the first element with the last one. I want to modify this code further to create a bubble sort algorithm, I am just confused at how to get done what I just explained.

Updated : Thanks for the answer that I should change "ls[i]=a" with "a=ls[i]", but can someone explain to me how this differs in logic?

Comment: *"doesnt work right"*?

Comment: Can you clarify "swap consecutive elements of a list"?  How is this swapping consecutive elements?

Comment: it prints [7, 3, 4, 3, 8] instead of [7,3,4,3,4]

Comment: swapping in pairs. eg the first element will swap with the second then the second with the third and so on

Comment: Just change the first line in `while` loop to `a = ls[i]`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop to move the first element to the last. Just pop the first element off the list, then append it.

```
ls.append(ls.pop(0))
```

Comment: I know I can do that but i want to swap the elements one by one in pairs from left to right

Comment: unless you pass an index, then it removes the element at that index.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh " list.pop([i]) Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in the list. "

Comment: @HogRider123 why?

Comment: "i want to swap the elements one by one in pairs from left to right" ... er, no you don't. :-)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh because I have to work on this code further and modify it to create a bubble sort algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Python allows to work with [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) by selecting one or several elements at the time and to concatenate the content of the `list`

```
ls = [4, 7, 3, 4, 3]
new_list_with_first_element_at_the_end = ls[1:] + [ls[0]]
```

Comment: In principle yes, but... did you try this?

Comment: Yeah, you can only add a sequence and `ls[0]` isn't a list. Should be `... + [ls[0]]`

Answer (score 1):

If you really feel you must, make a `swap` function:

```
def swap(l, i, j):
    tmp = l[j]
    l[j] = i
    l[i] = tmp
```

Then you can:

```
for i in range(len(l)-1):
     swap(l, i, i+1)
```

Comment: `tmp` is not needed, you can just do `l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]`